# Android Background threads: Difference between launching from an Activity and from a Service

Tags: android

Is there any difference in running background threads from an `Activity` and from a `Service` that is started by the `Activity`? *Added:* The background threads do not interact with the UI.

I currently have some background threads that are launched from the `Activity`. Most are via `AsyncTask` and one is through my own `ExecutorService`. I would like to know if there is a significant benefit to refactoring the code to move these to a `Service` or `IntentService`.

Comment: It depends on what your `AsyncTasks` do. The point of an `AsyncTask` is that it acts as a 'bridge' between a background thread and the Activity UI. If you don't need any pre/post interaction with the UI or progress updates as to what the thread is doing then an `AsyncTask` isn't necessary. As a result you can either simply invoke a generic `Thread` in your `Activity` or farm the work out to a `Service`.

Comment: a Service can out live the Activity, I believe that an AsyncTask cannot. and like Squonk said, UI interaction is easier with AsyncTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the definition of Activities and Services.  To make it clear:

- *Activities* are things that run according to the Activity lifecycle state machine.  The code in the respective handlers interacts with an event loop attached to a UI.
- *Services* are things that run according to the Service lifecycle state machine.  The code in the respective lifecycle handlers performs operations to handle things like Intents, etc..., but does *not* interact with the user via a UI.

Both of these, however, run on the "main thread" of the application.  By itself, an Activity or a Service (or Broadcast Receiver, Content provider, etc...) is *not* a thread.  Look at the documentation, and you will see that the Activity and Service classes do not, in fact, form a thread.  Instead, they are hooks that will run inside the Android framework, and the framework will at the appropriate time call them on the "main" thread of the app.

You can *create* separate threads for the app, or use an `AsyncTask` to do work and publish it to the UI thread easily (something not so easily achieved with a Service).

Comment: Thanks. I do know the definition of Activities and Services, how they handle the main thread, and I can create separate threads or the `AsyncTask` on the UI thread. I wanted to know the difference from doing it from the Activity or the Service.

Comment: @mparaz with respect to how they are handled, they should be no different.  I.e., starting a thread in a service won't be handled differently than in an activity.

Answer (score 1):

Threads that are bound to Activities have the same lifecycle. So if you restart/kill the Activity, the thread will also be restarted/killed. This is a problem if you don't manage the lifecycle of an Activity. A service is good in this case. You can have the activity destroyed and still a worker thread running in the background (in the service). But be advised that, if the Android system need resources (memory for example) it will kill the services first (and then restart them according to their Sticky flag). In my opinion, there are no actual benefit in changing threads from the Activity to a Service, since you control the workflow of your activity. If the threads are heavy (and brake the UI for moments) consider putting them in a service on a separate process (in AndroidManifest put the process name of the service).

In Android documentation:

> Caution: Another problem you might encounter when using a worker
>   thread is unexpected restarts in your activity due to a runtime
>   configuration change (such as when the user changes the screen
>   orientation), which may destroy your worker thread. To see how you can
>   persist your task during one of these restarts and how to properly
>   cancel the task when the activity is destroyed, see the source code
>   for the Shelves sample application.

Comment: **So if you restart/kill the Activity, the thread will also be restarted/killed.** - Yes and no. It is possible to persist an `AsyncTask` and re-attach the `Activity` to it in the case of a screen orientation change, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Have you seen the benefits of moving the threads to another process? I don't see how this will improve it, and, I believe there is overhead in running in a separate process.

Comment: I have seen great benefits with heavy cpu/io threads (parsing 15MB  xml and writing to database).